# Tree-Conflict when Merging with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge

I have a repository in which I've created a branch which got its development over today. But there were some changes on the trunk so I have to merge the trunk into branch then continue the process.

First I tried to use the reintegrate feature on eclipse, but I get an error:

```
Merge operation failed
svn: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 'http://192.168.0.1/svn/gestaoconfig'"
```

Then I tried to use the main tab (URL) which should be normal, but somehow all the files are marked in conflict, and the changes made on the trunk do not appear on the local development. The diff shows exactly the same files.

I've tried attached the preview message of eclipse, but I couldn't.

> My environment:
>
> local development: ubuntu 12, using eclipse helios, with svn, version
>   1.6.17 (r1128011).
>
> Repository server: fedora 12, with svn, version 1.6.9 (r901367).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you might want to check out trunk and branch separately and check whether its feasible to do manual diff and merge.

Comment: I've tried a manual merge and it's worked fine. But I had to make it by console. Would you know why did eclipse make this mess?

Comment: There are some 1.6.x  subversion versions that have problems even depending on the platform. For Eclipse there are several options on how to configure your team provider. The whole thing can get really messy if you add 64bit and 32 bit platform differences. At BITPlan we have migrated to git two month ago two avoid these problems. So I can't even try out your problem any more without extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
Merge operation failed
svn: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 'http://192.168.0.1/svn/gestaoconfig'"
```

This means that your server is not at least version 1.5. I would highly suggest to upgrade your server because merges before this revision were quite hazardous since they had to be handled entirely manually.

However *reintegrate merges* are designed for the case where you worked on a feature branch and want to reintegrate it into the trunk or another branch. You are not expected to continue working on a reintegrated branch (see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate)).

In your case you probably just want a normal merge. If you did not delete/rename/move any file/folder in the trunk nor the branch, then your tree conflict probably comes from an error in the source or target merge path (e.g. you did not specify the `/trunk` or `/branches/mybranch` in the url)

Comment: You're right. But, wasn't better using reintegrate? Using the normal merge worked fine.

Comment: In fact, I'm using 1.6.13 (I've upgraded from 1.6.9). Shouldn't it work?

Comment: I don't think reintegrate applies in your case, check the link I provided in my answer. Concerning the version of svn, the problem is the server-side version: the version of the server you are using does not keep merge history (a.k.a. mergeinfo) and hence does not support reintegrate. Neither will it be able to know what has been merged and what has not.